# Rexex htaccess 404 error

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to get all request to the server to go to the index.php file with the request information.

Also, I want to prevent accessing the index.php file directly.

The second part works fine but I can't do the first part for some reason

```
  #If the request is for index - prevent from accessing the file directly
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php(.*)$ - [F,L]

#If the request if not for the receiver - redirect to the api server
#RewriteCond !^(*.)campaigns/(\d+)/pictures(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule  index.php?request=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Questions about webserver configuration should be asked on https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

(.*) is a greedy match, so it will eat everything. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

adding the "`?`". However do you really need the first `(.*)` at all? Are you only looking to capture content after the ".php"? Why do you have two `(.*)`, but you are only backreferencing one?